# Equivalence of Dirichlet problems. Gilbarg & Trudinger

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I do not understand the proof of theorem 11.4 in the book "Elliptic Partial Differential Equations of Second Order" by Gilbarg & Trudinger. The reason is that I do not understand the text right before the theorem (about $T$ operator and the equivalence stated in page 281.)

The problem is, I do not see why the problems $u=\sigma Tu$ and $Q_\sigma$ are equivalent.

[page 281 of Gilbarg](http://wstaw.org/w/3nWV/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just plugin the definition of $T$ and $Q_\sigma$. We have 
$$ u = \sigma Tu \iff Tu = \frac{u}{\sigma} $$
that is, by definition of $T$ iff $v := \frac{u}\sigma$ is the (unique) solution of 
$$ a^{ij}(x,u,Du)D_{ij}v + b(x,u,Du) = 0, \quad v|_{\partial \Omega} = \phi $$
Let here $v = \frac u\sigma$, this gives 
$$ \frac 1\sigma a^{ij}(x,u,Du) D_{ij}u + b(x,u,Du) = 0, \quad \frac{u}{\sigma}\biggr|_{\partial \Omega} = \phi $$
which is true only iff (multiply with $\sigma$)
$$ a^{ij}(x,u,Du)D_{ij} u + b(x,u, Du) = 0 ,\quad u|_{\partial \Omega} = \sigma\phi $$
that is iff (by definition) $0 = Q_\sigma u$